# How do we convert a string into Array in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using hive 1.1

```
 hive> select country from releases limit 1;
 OK
 ["us","ca","fr"]
```

For now country  is of type string in hive . How do I convert that into Array[String]?

I tried the below, but it is throwing error

```
 hive> select country, cast(country as Array[String]) from releases limit 1;
 FAILED: ParseException line 1:48 cannot recognize input near 'Array' '[' 'String' in primitive type specification
```

Can someone help me to do the typecasting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
hive> with releases as (select '["us","ca","fr"]' as country)
    > select  split(regexp_extract(country,'^\\["(.*)\\"]$',1),'","')
    > from    releases
    > ;
OK
_c0
["us","ca","fr"]
```

Answer (score 0):

a way without `regexp_extract`

```sql
SELECT country, split(substr(country, 3, length(country) - 4),'","') AS arr FROM releases LIMIT 1;
```