# Distinct value from array looking field type that is a string?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a field where rows look something like this:

```
["apples", "pears", "grapes"]
["apples"]
["pears", "bananas", "grapes"]
```

When I do `describe mytable` the field is a string type.

As opposed to `select distinct myfield` I'm seeking a way to select the distinct values after splitting, something like:

```
select distinct split(myfield, ',')
```

Is there a way to do this in Hive SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the following way. You will need to `replace` the brackets and `split` by comma to get the array. After that you can [explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode(array)) your array.

```
select distinct(explodedfield) 
from mytable 
lateral view 
explode(split( replace(replace(myfield,"]",""),"[","") , ",") ) 
f as explodedfield;
```

If you want to replace the quotation marks as well, you can take a look to this answer [How do we convert a string into Array in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965889/how-do-we-convert-a-string-into-array-in-hive)